# Loading content fails while switching routes in Vue.js 2. Why?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

guys. I'm just getting started with Vue.js 2 and I'm trying to create an app that is functionally similar to the RGB Challenge game. I've gone a step further and added difficulties (easy, medium hard and expert) which would be under router links /difficulty/(easy, medium, hard and expert) respectively. I've got much of the functionality just fine, so far.

Now, what I'd like is for the content under each router to correspond to the appropriate difficulty (level). What this simply means, is that if I click on, say, easy, only five colored boxes (divs) ought to be loaded and displayed. Medium difficulty should correspond to ten, hard to 20 and expert to 25. This is where I have a problem. When the page loads for the first time and I click on, say, expert, I will have the 25 boxes. However, when I try switching from this to any of the other links/difficulties, nothing changes, and I still have the same 25 boxes from expert level. The corresponding number of boxes (divs) simply do not load.

Below are the relevant code snippets. I did not include styling.

Also, I am yet to fully add the functionality for the GameInfo.vue component, so ignore it. I'd appreciate any pointers.

**App Component**

> ```
> <template>
>   <div id="app">
>     <h1 class="text-center">
>       <router-link to="/">
>         The Great<br>
>         <span>RGB</span><br>
>         Guessing Challenge
>       </router-link>
>     </h1>
>     <NavBar></NavBar>
>     <router-view></router-view>
>     <footer class="text-center">
>       <p>Copyright&copy; 2017 Collins Orlando</p>
>     </footer>
>   </div>
> </template> 
>
> <script>
> import NavBar from './components/NavBar'
>
> export default {
>   name: 'app',
>   components: {
>     NavBar
>   }
> }
> </script>
> ```

**NavBar Component**

```
<template>
  <div class="navbar">
        <nav class="text-center">
            <ul>
                <li><router-link to="/difficulty/easy">Easy</router-link></li>
                <li><router-link to="/difficulty/medium">Medium</router-link></li>
                <li><router-link to="/difficulty/hard">Hard</router-link></li>
                <li><router-link to="/difficulty/expert">Expert</router-link></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'navbar'
}
</script>
```

**Difficulty Component**

```
<template>
    <div id="difficulty"> 
        <GameInfo :gameData="gameData"></GameInfo>
        <div class="container">
            <div 
                class="colorBox" 
                v-for="bgColor in colorItems.colorsArray" 
                :style="{ background: bgColor}"
                @click="checkCorrectColor"
            >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template> 

<script>
    import GameInfo from './GameInfo'
    
    export default {
        components: {
            GameInfo
       },
        data() { 
            return {
                score: 0,
              tries: 0,
              randomColor: () => {
                    let r   = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256),
                        g   = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256),
                        b   = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256),
                        rgb = 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
                       
                    return rgb;
              },
              colorItems: {},
              guessedColor: '',
              num: 0,
              gameData: {}
            }
        },
        methods: {
            numberOfColors() {
                let difficulty = this.$route.params.id;

              if(difficulty === 'expert') {
                this.num = 25;
              }
              else if(difficulty === 'hard') {
                this.num = 20;
              }
              else if(difficulty === 'medium') {
                this.num = 10;
              } else {
                this.num = 5;
              }
              return this.num;
           },
            generateColorsArray () {
              let colors         = [],
                  colorToGuess   = '';

              while(colors.length < this.numberOfColors()) {
                colors.push(this.randomColor());
              }

              this.colorItems.colorsArray = colors;
              this.colorItems.colorToGuess = colors[Math.floor((Math.random() * colors.length))];

              return this.colorItems;
           },
           checkCorrectColor(e) {
            this.guessedColor = e.target.style.backgroundColor;
                if(this.guessedColor !== this.coloritems.colorToGuess) {
                    console.log(this.guessedColor);
                    this.tries++;
                } else {
                    console.log('I am Groot');
                }
           }
        },
        created() {
            this.generateColorsArray();
            this.gameData.score = this.score;
            this.gameData.tries = this.tries;
            this.gameData.colors = this.colorItems;
            console.log(this.gameData)
        }
    }
</script>
```

**index.js (Routes)**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from '@/components/Home'
import Difficulty from '@/components/Difficulty'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
        path: '/difficulty/:id',
      name: 'Difficulty',
      component: Difficulty
    }
  ]
})
```

**main.js (Instanciation)**

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Route components in Vue Router 2 are always reused whenever possible. This means the `Difficulty` component is not re-created when you navigate to a different difficulty, and it performs initialization in the `created` hook which will not be called when the route changes.

You need to use the [`beforeRouteUpdate`](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html) navigation guard to re-initialize the component with the new difficulty (and possible reset the state of the component if required).

```js
methods: {
  reset() {
    this.generateColorsArray();
    this.gameData.score = this.score;
    this.gameData.tries = this.tries;
    this.gameData.colors = this.colorItems;
    console.log(this.gameData)
  },
},

created() {
  this.reset();
},

beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
  // This check may not be necessary depending on your router configuration
  // and if you have other intermediate route components
  if (from.params.id !== to.params.id) {
    this.reset();
  }

  next();
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will look into it.